# Bash Shell Script: Diff command conflicting line format

Tags: windows, bash, shell, diff

I am using Windows OS.

My program:

```
#!/bin/bash

    OIFS="$IFS"
    IFS=$'\n'

    find teste1 -type f | while read -r firstResult

    do

      find teste2 -type f | while read -r secondResult

       do

        firstName=${firstResult##*[/|\\]}
        secondName=${secondResult##*[/|\\]}

         if [[ "$( echo "$firstName" | tr [A-Z] [a-z])" == "$( echo "$secondName" | tr [A-Z] [a-z])" ]]; then
          echo "$firstResult" "$secondResult" >> equal
         else
          echo "$firstResult" "$secondResult" >> notEqual
         fi

         if [[ $firstName == $secondName ]]; then
          echo "$firstResult" "$secondResult" >> equal2
         fi

       done

    done

    diff -2 "--line-format=%L" "--unchanged-line-format=" equal equal2 > renamedFiles.lst

    rm equal
    rm equal2
    rm notEqual
```

Whenever I run this program, it says "diff: conflicting line format". However, it produces the "renamedFiles.lst" and produces exactly the way I want. So, why is it giving me this answer? Can I fix it? It doesn't really affect my program but no one likes seeing warnings / errors on their programs, right? :)

Comment: Why are you calling a bash script a "windows shell" script?

Comment: Because I am using Windows OS?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you are using *both* `--line-format` (to format **all** lines) and `--unchanged-line-format` (to format unchanged lines). I guess `diff` doesn't define what to do if it gets conflicting format specifiers, so it fails and tells you about it. What you could do is use for example `--old-line-format=%L --new-line-format=%L --unchanged-line-format=`

Comment: Indeed, THANKS A LOT! :) That did solve it :P Still kept my formatting like I wanted (same as the program I had) but no longer gave out the message. Seems weird though that it doesn't change the format but no longer gives the message either. Either way, thanks for the help, it's solved.